# using owl:equivalentClass with subClasses in OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege, rdfs

I'm trying to learn how to use the owl:equivalentClass property (called **Equivalent To** in Protégé) with SubClasses on my ontology example which is the following:

```
Plant  
L Angiosperm   (subClass of Plant)   
L Gymnosperm   (subClass of Plant)
```

Now I added 2 object properties to those 2 subClasses to bind them to their SuperClass in this way:

```
Plant hasFlowers Angiosperm   ------- (exp: meaning that a Plant that has flowers is an Angiosperm)   
Plant hasNoFlowers Gymnosperm
```

What I want to achieve is to express the sameAs property through the properties I made in Protégé but I am not getting how to do it, I would like to express something like this:

```
Angiosperm <someRandomProp> <someData>   
"Equivalent To"   
(Plant hasFlowers) <someRandomProp> <someData>
```

EDITED: cleared out the property name

Comment: By "equivalentTo", do you mean `owl:equivalentClass` or is it a property you want to define ? If it's the former, then edit your question accordingly. If it's the latter, then I have no idea what you want to do. So edit your question accordingly.

Comment: apparently the protégé guide didn't explain which owl property is referring to with the "Equivalent To" tag of the UI and I had to check to be sure, I was incorrect by saying it was owl:sameAs, it is owl:equivalentClass instead as you suggested, I edited all the ambiguities and hope that the question is clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use object properties between two classes - only annotation properties can be used that way.

The meaning you're trying to express is that a Plant which has flowers is an Angiosperm - to do this, you wish to assert that Angiosperm is equivalent to the class of Plants and the class of things that have flowers, so you'd have an existential restriction on the property, and intersect it with a named concept.

From memory, this should be typed as

```
EquivalentClasses (Angiosperm, (Plant and some hasFlowers Thing))
```

(It does not matter what the domain and range of hasFlowers are at this point).

Comment: Thanks for your help and your explaination, this cleared out some doubts i had about those properties and how they work together. I see that the object properties i made don't make sense, so i am going to see how to sort this out with annotation properties